# UnboundLocalError-local variable 'app' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

bu benim appname.urls kodlarım [appname: atolye (bu bir Türk kelimesi)]

from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [

```
url(r'^index/$', atolye_index),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', atolye_detail),
```

]
ve bu benim atolye.views

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import atolye

def atolye_index(request):
    atolyes=atolye.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'atolye_index.html', {'atolyes':atolyes})

def atolye_detail(request, id):
    atolye = get_object_or_404(atolye, id=id)
    context = {
        'atolye': atolye,
    }
    return render(request, 'atolye_detail.html', context)
Bu kodu kullanmak istiyorum ama işe yaramıyor. Ne yapmalıyım?

python: 3.5.3 django: 1.10 win7 Yeni bir kullanıcıyım. Kötü ingilizcem için özür dilerim.

Comment: Is this actually the code the error comes from?

Comment: Anyway, please (1) give us the whole exception (with the traceback), not just a description of it, (2) format your code as code, and (3) make sure what you've given us is enough to diagnose the problem. (See [mcve] in the help if needed; there's a lot of useful guidance there on what is helpful.)

Comment: the error comes from url in browser, when i write "http://127.0.0.1:8000/atolye/1/"

Comment: Why have you edited your question to be in Turkish rather than English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a guess here, because your exception traceback doesn't match either your title or your description, and your code is unreadable, but…

```
from .models import atolye

# …

def atolye_detail(request, id):
    atolye = get_object_or_404(atolye, id=id)
```

This last line is probably the one with the exception, and the unbound local is probably not `app` or the other one you mentioned but `atolye`, right?

The problem is that if you assign to a name anywhere in a function, that name is always a local variable in that function.

So, since you have `atolye =` here, `atolye` is a local variable. Even in `get_object_or_404(atolye, id=id)`. And, since that call happens before you've assigned anything to `atolye`, the local variable has no value.

---

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but there are two possibilities.

If you weren't trying to replace the global value of `atolye`, just use a different name:

```
def atolye_detail(request, id):
    my_atolye = get_object_or_404(atolye, id=id) 
    context = { 'atolye': my_atolye, }
    return render(request, 'atolye_detail.html', context)
```

If you *were* trying to replace the global value of `atolye`, you need a `global`statemen:

```
def atolye_detail(request, id):
    global atolye
    atolye = get_object_or_404(atolye, id=id) 
    context = { 'atolye': atolye, }
    return render(request, 'atolye_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: this first is working thank you bro